Regex search for pattern and return group
I have a text to search in like this:
process ADT {
    { DOMAINNAME localdomain }
    { EODEFAULT {} }
    { EOXLATE {} }
    { XLATESTARTMODE 0 }
} 
process ORU {
    { DOMAINNAME localdomain }
    { EODEFAULT {} }
    { EOXLATE {} }
    { SMATCYCLESIZE 100 }
    { TRACINGDEFAULT 0 }
    { XLATE {
    { XLATESTARTMODE 0 }
}

My regex pattern is:
^process \w* {

With this I found two matches:

process ADT {
process ORU {

That result it near what I want.
I want to get the whole text until the next match:
Match 1:
process ADT {
    { DOMAINNAME localdomain }
    { EODEFAULT {} }
    { EOXLATE {} }
    { XLATESTARTMODE 0 }
} 

And Match 2:
process ORU {
    { DOMAINNAME localdomain }
    { EODEFAULT {} }
    { EOXLATE {} }
    { SMATCYCLESIZE 100 }
    { TRACINGDEFAULT 0 }
    { XLATE {
    { XLATESTARTMODE 0 }
} 

How can I realize that?

Using what regex tool exactly? Please review the usage guidance for the Stack Overflow regex tag and then [edit] your question accordingly to mention the target tool or platform both in the tags and in the question itself.


^process \w+ \{(?:\n .*)*\n}, 2) ^process\s+\w+\s*\{[\w\W]*?\n\s*}\s*$ or 3) (splitting) ^(?!\A)(?=process \w* \{) - does this work for you?


Here is a pure regex solution which seems to be working:
^process \w+ \{.*?(?<=\n)\}(?!\S)

This matches each process block, one at a time, with the closing \} being defined as preceded by newline and followed also by newline or the end of the string.
Explanation:

^ from the start of the string
process match literal process
  space
\w+ process name
  space
\{ opening bracket
.*? then match all content, across newlines, until reaching the nearest
(?<=\n)\} closing bracket, preceded by newline
(?!\S) and followed by newline or end of the string.

Note: If your regex tool does not support dot all mode, then use this version to match across newlines:
^process \w+ \{[\s\S]*?(?<=\n)\}(?!\S)

Here is a link to working regex demo.
